# portable on a sd card Android

Tags: android, memory-management, storage

My problem is: my app doesn't install sd card. But I write this code ;

```
 android:installLocation="auto"
```

I write this code, the app when I install .apk from bluetooth. It is possible to move sd card but when I install apk from android market it is not possible to move sd card. Why???

Comment: have you tried this .if not try in android manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using Android Market's "copy protection" feature? If so, then it will override android:installLocation and only allow the user to install it on internal storage.

Also, if you prefer that your app be installed on an external device, you should use preferExternal rather than auto.

For further reference:
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html

Comment: Yes android market's copy protection feature. What can i do? 
 android:installLocation="preferExternal" this not work too.

How can ı use licencing service?